# Check My Understanding of cat and Posix Tee

Tags: posix, cat, io-redirection, tee

```
cat < existingInputFile | tee newOutputFile > newOutputFile2
```

1. cat command is executed and the result is written in a file names existingInputFile
2. then send the output of existingInputFile to tee
3. after that I am lost...

does tee get the existingInputFile and instead of outputing to the terminal  duplicates the file content to newOutputFile and newOutputFile2?

Please explain in detail. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The file existingInputFile is used as the input for cat as the "<" indicates. Cat is a very simply (but useful!) program that simply returns it's input to the default output.

The default output is redirected to the program tee as the "|" indicates. Tee sends it's input to the default output AND to a file. As the default output is redirected to a file using the ">" sign, the default output is also written to a file.